# dynamicly show/hide columns based on cell value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to google script and i need help with something. 
I have spreadsheet with 6 diffrent sheets in it for my coworkers ("coworker 1","coworker 2" ect.) Each of those coworkers has his own spreadsheet and my "master spreadsheet" imports data from their spreads using IMPORTRANGE function.
In cell M2 they have dropdown list where they can select value from 1-10(that corresponds to next 10 columns after column M - from N to column W). What i need to happend is for spreadsheet to read those values imported in cell M2 and show me that amount of columns next to column M and hide the rest of the 10 columns. For example. If in M2 imported value is 2 I want to show colmn N and O and hide columns P-W and if the value is 10 then show all columns N-W. And i need this to work for all 6 sheets in my spreadsheet. Thank You for any help and sorry for my poor english!

Comment: Can you share code and data?

Comment: Do you want the solution to read M2 from the coworkers spreadsheets or from your imported data on your coworker copied sheets?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
function hideCoworkerColumns()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sA=['CoWorker1','CoWorker2','CoWorker3','CoWorker4','CoWorker5','CoWorker6'];
  var cA=[14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23];
  for(var i=0;i<sA.length;i++)
  {
    var sheet=ss.getSheetByName(sA[i]);
    if(sheet)
    {
      var show=sheet.getRange('M2').getValue();
      for(var j=0;j<cA.length;j++)
      {
        if(j>=show)
        {
          sheet.hideColumns(cA[j]);
        }
        else
        {
          sheet.showColumns(cA[j]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```